# How to authorize using windows authentication in ASP.net 5

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, windows-authentication

I am creating an application which is going to use windows authentication to allow access to page based on user and its roles. I have gone ahead and configured IIS to use windows authentication and disabled anonymous access. I am able to browse the application without any issue and I have successfully enabled windows authentication for the application.

Now I am trying to set access to controller level by using `Authorize`, but I am unable to figure it out how it works with ASP.net 5. I am completely new to ASP / C# programming platform but I did search online resources and I came across [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg703322(VS.98).aspx) and I used below example to give it a try but I get red squiggly line under `users` and I think ASP.NET 5 is unable to find `users`. I also made sure that I have added all the references at the top.

```
[Authorize(Users = @"CONTOSO\Rick, CONTOSO\Keith, CONTOSO\Mike")]
```

References:

```
using Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc;
using RMDAAutomation.Models.Repository;
using RMDAAutomation.Models.Entity;
using Microsoft.AspNet.Authorization;
```

Any suggestions is highly appreciated. :)

**UPDATE 1:**

TutorialsController.cs:

```
using Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc;
using Microsoft.AspNet.Authorization;

namespace RMDAAutomation.Controllers.Web
{
    public class TutorialsController : Controller
    {
        [Authorize(Roles = @"DOMAIN\GROUP")]
        public IActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }
    }
}
```

Tutorial Index View:

```
<div class="container">
    <h1>Tutorials</h1>

</div>
```

Visual studio project settings:
[image]

Comment: Try to implement roles instead of users. it gives you more flexibility. so you can manage roles that have 1 or more users. for instance you can use 
`[Authorize(Roles = "Administrator")]` to authorize all users with the role `Administrator`

Comment: When you hover over the "red squiggly line" what does the error message say?

Comment: Don't use ASP.NET 5 if you are new to ASP / C#. ASP.NET 5 is not yet ready and changes a lot of APIs, so most of the documentation you find for older releases is invalid. Stick to ASP.NET 4.6. At least until 5 is ready.

Comment: To all, thanks for your response. @Alundrathedreamwalker, I will try your suggestion as I am able to see that in intellisense. @Ashley - when I hover over `Users` I get `The type or namespace name Users could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?`). @SoonDead - I disagree, ASP.NET 5 is now RC1 and production ready. It doesnt make any sense for me to learn asp.net 4 or lower version as ASP.NET is built from the ground.

Comment: @Alundrathedreamwalker - I tried your suggestion, but I get 403 forbidden error.

Comment: @Ray you will need yo implement more things than just that line. Will send you code if needed

Comment: Just added my code. :)

Answer (score -3):

```
using System.Web.Mvc;
```

This using solves the issue in my project

Comment: This has absolutely nothing to do with authentication. It simply imports the namespace so you can use Mvc classes.

Comment: The opener asked for "...I get red squiggly line...." - and namespaces often solve those.

Comment: @maltmann, thank you for your response. However that doesnt solve my problem.